# How can i compare two port bits if they are equal ,greater than or smaller than each other?

Tags: assembly, 8051

I am working on an 8051 assembler and i wanted to know a command that will help me to compare between two port bits and find if they are equal or not and so i searched for it and found that CJNE might be useful and tried to put it in a program as following ...i am not sure if i am going in the right path maybe an Xnor command is better but i cant find one for it and i can't test it for some reason.

```
 ORG 00H
 MOV R0 ,#01H
 MOV R1, #00H
 CJNE  R0,#00H,LOOP
 LOOP: MOV C, P1.0
 ANL C,P3.0
 MOV P2.0,C 
 SJMP LOOP
 END
```

And if i wanted to know if one port bit is greater or smaller than other can i use an ANL command??

Answer (score 4):

Not an expert on 8051 but after the comparison, the zero flag is set if it's equal (branch EQ or NE) and the carry flag if it's greater (CS or CC for set or clear). After CJNE (compare and jump if not equal), you can then check the carry flag with JC [destination for carry set - ie >]. No need to do a second comparison - the flags will still be set from the first.

```
CJNE  R0,#00H,NOTEQUAL
; equal code goes here, then branch out
NOTEQUAL:
JC GREATER
; less than code goes here, then branch out
GREATER:
; greater code goes here
```

JNC is the instruction for the carry flag not being set - ie it's less than or equal but you've already eliminated equal so it would be less than.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it. It is by no means Cycle or Code effective but it does what you ask for.

Lets say you want to compare if P1.0 and P2.0 are equal with the following results. (P3.0, P3.1, and P3.2 are result indicators)

P1.0 = P2.0, set P3.0 else cleared

P1.0 > P2.0, set P3.1 else cleared

P1.0 = P2.0 = 0, set P3.2 else cleared

```
    org 00H

    MOV    P3DIR, #0x00   ; Set direction of P3...

Start:
    JB    P1.0,   P1Set
    JB    P2.0,   P1NotSetP2Set
    SJMP  None
P1Set:
    JB    P2.0,   P1SetP2Set
    SJMP  P1SetP2NotSet
P1SetP2Set:
    SETB  P3.0
    CLRB  P3.1
    CLRB  P3.2
    SJMP  Start
P1SetP2NotSet:
    CLR   P3.0
    SETB  P3.1
    CLR   P3.2
    SJMP  Start
P1NotSetP2Set:
    CLR   P3.0
    CLR   P3.1
    CLR   P3.2
    SJMP  Start
None:
    SETB  P3.0
    CLR   P3.1
    SETB  P3.1
    SJMP  Start

    end
```